# Lose my data by installing Linux on a separate SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, windows-11, data-transfer

So recently I bought a new separate SSD which runs on a 2.5 inch to USB 3.0, i have around 300 Gb of data, no OP system, my main OP is running on M.2 SSD inside my PC, my doubt is could I lose data if install it to a separate partition on my separate SSD. Could that happen? (I am not a technology noob, I know how to install an OP, and install TWRP and a different OS on my Phone)

Comment: If you know what you're doing, namely how to manage partitions, why would there be a problem? Needless to say, ALWAYS have backups if the data is important.